# server internal error with mod_wsgi and apache2

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've been trying to deploy django-oscar's sandbox website on a server with mod_wsgi and apache2.

The thing is, whenever I open the website's address, i get a 500 error with the following in my log :

```
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200] mod_wsgi (pid=28331): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8001:1000/htdocs/en-gb'.
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server/__init__.py", line 1299, in handle_request
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     return self.application(environ, start_response)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py", line 24, in application
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     return _application(environ, start_response)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 231, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     'request': request
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1166, in error
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1258, in _log
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     self.handle(record)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1268, in handle
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     self.callHandlers(record)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1308, in callHandlers
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     hdlr.handle(record)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 748, in handle
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     self.emit(record)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 929, in emit
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     self.stream = self._open()
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oscar/core/logging/handlers.py", line 26, in _open
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     return BaseFileHandler._open(self)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 916, in _open
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200]     stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
[Fri May 22 16:53:48 2015] [error] [client 2.190.60.200] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/logs/errors.log'
```

now I don't know what I've done wrong here, since I'm quite new at this. I know that there are two things wrong at once! First an exception happens in the script and second the log can't be written into the logfile because of a permission problem!

now here is my wsgi.py script:

```
import os
import sys
import site
import urllib

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

# Project root
root = '/var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox'
sys.path.insert(0, root)

# Packages from virtualenv
activate_this = '/var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/oscar/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

# Set environmental variable for Django and fire WSGI handler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = urllib.unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')[0])
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

and this is my apache2 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        WSGIDaemonProcess setak python-path=/var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox:/var/www/setak/setakenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup setak
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py
        ServerAdmin admin@setakshop.ir
        ServerName shop.setakshop.ir

        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/static/robots.txt

        Alias /media/ /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/media/
        Alias /static/ /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/static/

        <Directory /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/static>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/media>
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I also run the project with the command :

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server wsgi.py --port=8001     --user www-data --group www-data
```

and also the simpler command :

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server wsgi.py --port=8001
```

but the same thing happens.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try my script. Simple as it gets. https://github.com/limtaesu/django-easy-deploy

Comment: looks like you need to set the permissions on your log folder

Comment: @taesu I would actually like to fix this and avoid any other django extensions and packages, since they were the only thing that got me here, but thanks!

Comment: its not extension nor a package. it simply generates your .conf file.

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes I know dat, but there is also an exception thrown! and even if the permissions were right, I think we'd still have a problem. and btw I have tried many things like changing the owner of the directory to www-data and using this command : find django-oscar/ \( -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rx {} \; -o -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} \; \) -- but not fixed!

Comment: test this `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/logs/errors.log`

Comment: @itzmeontv as strange as this is, it actually solved both of the problems! there is now no exception thrown also. So I get that I have a permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing permission to `777`.But it is not recommended.(Try changing owner is good approach.)

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/logs/errors.log
```